# Jquery chosen longer than showed div with mouseout event closes div

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

how can I solve this problem please? I have div with form which is hidden by default.  It shows on click event and I want it to hide on mouse out - this is easy part.

But there is one problem, I am using jquery chosen - http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ for dropdown menu which is inside this div, but dropdown is longer than div. It mean, when I select some option, mouse pointer is outside of div with mouseout event and it hides when I move with mouse.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

jQuery is simple:

```
$('#header_form').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#header_form').hide();
});
```

Solution 1:
After hour of trying and coding I found one simple solution:
Inside #header_form create div with absolute position wide as #header_form and long as dropdown menu starting at dropdown menu position. Absolute positioned div will not affect background color of #header_form, but it will create invisible "layer" where you can move with mouse "outside" of #header_from without closing it. You need also remove this fix element when you move your mouse into original #header_form so when you move out again, div will hide.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/a5PuG/5/ (just change blue color to transparent) It still need some tweaks :)

Comment: This might be a problem with your HTML. Can you post the code for the navigation too, please?

Comment: Here is demo - http://jsfiddle.net/a5PuG/2/

Comment: I think you may want to rethink the way that you're doing this. It is going to be pretty tricky, and require a bit of messy javascript, to get this working the way you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited my answer after finding a better way.  You can actually do this fairly easily.  Change your code to this:

```
$('select').chosen();
var shouldHide;
$('#form').mouseleave(function() {
    if (shouldHide) $(this).hide();
})
.mouseover(function() {
    shouldHide = true;         
});
$('.chosen-container').mouseover(function() {
    shouldHide = false;
})
.mouseleave(function() {
    shouldHide = false;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5PuG/6/)

Comment: Thank you for reply, this is useful :). Your code has one imperfection for me, but it is my fault, I did not specified it. My form is showing on hover and I need it to hide on mouse out, but your solution dont hide form when I dont move mouse in form first.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite following you.  Your form should start invisible?  Is there a smaller button?  I could tweak the answer if required.  Maybe update your jsFiddle to show this functionality?

I'm happy to look at that, but if this is enough to fix your issue could you mark this as answer?

Comment: Yep you are right, form shows on hover effect of button and it is invisible at start. I'm trying to update it, but script use css z-indexes and it is not working on jsfiddle for some reason. On my site its working good - http://jsfiddle.net/a5PuG/10/